# OSS supported by Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

When I go to https://cloud.google.com/dataproc, I see this ...

"Dataproc is a fully managed and highly scalable service for running Apache Spark, Apache Flink, Presto, and 30+ open source tools and frameworks."

But `gcloud dataproc jobs submit` doesn't list all of them. It lists only 8 (hadoop, hive, pig, presto, pyspark, spark, spark-r, spark-sql). Any idea why?

```
~ gcloud dataproc jobs submit
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit) Command name argument expected.

Available commands for gcloud dataproc jobs submit:

      hadoop                  Submit a Hadoop job to a cluster.
      hive                    Submit a Hive job to a cluster.
      pig                     Submit a Pig job to a cluster.
      presto                  Submit a Presto job to a cluster.
      pyspark                 Submit a PySpark job to a cluster.
      spark                   Submit a Spark job to a cluster.
      spark-r                 Submit a SparkR job to a cluster.
      spark-sql               Submit a Spark SQL job to a cluster.

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud dataproc jobs submit --help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some OSS components are offered as [Dataproc Optional Components](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview). Not of all them have a job submit API, some (e.g., [Anaconda](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/anaconda), [Jupyter](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/jupyter)) don't need one, some (e.g., [Flink](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/flink), [Druid](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/druid)) might add in the future.

Some other OSS components are offered as libraries, e.g., [GCS connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage), [BigQuery connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/bigquery), Apache Parquet.